# How exactly does an ethernet switch work?

Tags: networking, wireshark, ethernet, lan

I understand that it's different than a hub in that instead of packets being broadcasted to all devices connected to the device, it knows exactly who requested the packet by looking at the MAC layer.

However, is it still possible to use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to intercept packets meant for other users of the switch? Or is this only a problem with ethernet hubs that doesn't affect switches due to the nature of how a switch works?

On a slightly off topic side note, what exactly is classified as a LAN? For example, imagine two separate ethernet switches are hooked up to a router. Would each switch be considered a separate LAN? What is the significance of having multiple LAN's within the same network?

Comment: Hubs do not broadcast, they are dumb devices that simply repeat the signal to all interfaces. Basically, a hub is a layer-1 device, a powered cable.

Comment: In other words, all connected devices receive all packets and decide whether or not to use them?

Comment: In other words, as each bit comes into the hub, it is amplified and repeated out every other interface. It has nothing to do with packets or frames. A hub is really just a powered cable.

Comment: How do the connected devices know whether or not the information is meant for them?

Comment: The same way they do if you directly connected two devices and one sends something not meant for the other out the interface. In any case, [so] is for programming questions, and your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Where should questions like this be asked?

Comment: You could try on [su], or [electronics.se]. This type of question would probably be closed on [networkengineering.se] or [sf] because they are for professionally managed business networks.

Answer (score 2):

> it knows exactly who requested the packet by looking at the MAC layer.

More exactly, the switch uses the MAC destination address to forward a frame to the port associated with that address. Addresses are automatically learned by looking at the MAC source address on received frames.

A switch is stateless, ie. is has no memory who requested which data. A layer-2 switch also has no understanding of IP packets, addresses or protocols. All a basic switch does is learn source addresses and forward by destination address.

> is it still possible to use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to intercept packets meant for other users of the switch?

Yes. You'll need a managed switch supporting port mirroring or SPANning. This doesn't intercept frames, it just copies them to the mirror port. If you need to actually *intercept* frames you have to put your interceptor in between the nodes (physically or logically).

With a repeater hub, every bit is repeated to every node in the collision domain, making monitoring effortless.

> what exactly is classified as a LAN?

This depends on who you ask and on the context. A LAN can be a layer-1 segment/bus aka collision domain (obsolete), a layer-2 segment (broadcast domain), a layer-3 subnet (mostly identical with an L2 segment) or a complete local network installation (when contrasted with SAN or WAN).

Comment: When the first packet is sent to the destination, how can the sender possibly know the MAC address of the intended recipient? Without knowing the MAC address, if the intended recipient is connected to a switch, how would the switch know who to give the packet to?

Comment: Most often, the destination has already sent some broadcast or other, updating the switches - a DHCP discovery, ARP response or similar. If all else fails and the switch really doesn't know the destination MAC it emulates a repeater and floods the frame out of all its ports but the ingress port.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Zac67:

Regarding this question:

> is it still possible to use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to
> intercept packets meant for other users of the switch?

There are also active ways in which you can trick the Switch into sending you data that is meant for other machines. By exploiting the Switch's mechanism, one can send a frame with a spoofed source MAC, and then the Switch will transfer frames destined to this MAC - to the sender's port (until someone else sends a frame with that MAC address).

This video discusses this in detail:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVcBShtWFmo&list=PL9lx0DXCC4BMS7dB7vsrKI5wzFyVIk2Kg&index=18

In general, I recommend the following video that explains this in detail and in a visual way:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Youk8eUjkgQ&list=PL9lx0DXCC4BMS7dB7vsrKI5wzFyVIk2Kg&index=17

> what exactly is classified as a LAN?

So indeed this is one of the least-well-defined terms in Computer Networks. With regards to the Data Link Layer, a LAN can be defined as a **segment**, that is - a **broadcast domain**. In this case, two devices are regarded as part of the same **segment** iff they are one hop away from one another - that is, they can switch frames in the second layer.